# How to use a Nuxt component to pass a parameter to a vuex getter method? (while maintaining three dot notation)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, getter-setter

**GOAL:** I would like to watch a vuex state object (MATCH_DATA) for changes, specific to the value of a prop (topicId). So, I would like to set the watcher to watch MATCH_DATA[topicId]. And whenever MATCH_DATA[topicId] updates, I'd like to call a function (in this early case just logging it).

However, since MATCH_DATA is a getter how would I pass a parameter to it? The vuex getter does not seem to be designed to take in parameters. I have seen some examples by explicitly calling this.$store.state.etc.etc. but is there a way to do this while retaining the three dot notation I currently have?

Or, is there some better way of achieving this goal that does not involve a vuex getter?

**Current Code:**

Nuxt component:

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    props: ['topicId'],

    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('sessionStorage', ['MATCH_DATA']),
    },

    watch: {
        MATCH_DATA (newMatchData, oldMatchData) {
            console.log(newMatchData);
        }
    },
    
    mounted() {
        this.SUBSCRIBE_TO_TOPIC(this.topicId);
    },
    
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('sessionStorage', ['SUBSCRIBE_TO_TOPIC'])
    }
}
```

vuex store:

```
/* State */
export const state = () => ({
    MATCHES: {},
});

/* GETTERS */
export const getters = {
    MATCH_DATA: (state) => {
        return state.MATCHES;
    },
};
```

Comment: Not sure why you deleted your previous question..

Comment: @kissu that problem was just obfuscated by this one. The problem was that the object is created within MATCHES before the subscription. So watching MATCHES won't trigger any updates. It has to be the specific match object within MATCHES. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getter can simply return a function like this:

```js
export const getters = {
    MATCH_DATA: (state) => {
        return topicId => {
          // return something
        }}
    },
};
```

Then you can create a computed property to access those getter:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('sessionStorage', ['MATCH_DATA']),

    yourComputedProperty () {
      return this.MATCH_DATA(this.topicId)
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can watch the computed property to react on changes.

```js
watch: {
  yourComputedProperty (newData, oldData) {
    console.log(newData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how would I call that from the watched component?

Comment: I've updated the description. Does this work for you?

Comment: Close but I was looking to retain the three dot notation as the op states. Is that possible? I can use this method otherwise.

Comment: I don't use the three dot notation, but it should work as well. I've updated the answer again (at least with another computed property, or a method)